# Convert nested JSON to flat JSON - In order to insert them as records in SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string in nested pattern like below:

NESTED (Just Example):

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

I want an option or way to convert this nested JSON string to a flat JSON string so that I can insert them like a record in SQL table.

Can you please help on how to structure the JSON from nested to flat?

Comment: You need a recursive loop and `Object.keys`

Comment: What is wanted end result?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your expected end result won't really help much in saving it in SQL. The nesting itself is still data, giving context to the nested data. If you flatten it out you will lose that context

Comment: If you pass the json to yout ORM a string, it will be saved as  flat json string

Comment: please may you provide an expected result? and any context information like what is what and why would be useful too.